# pytest fixture to know if test skip

Tags: python, pytest

I define the teardown fixture as below

```
@pytest.fixture
def create_docker_image():
    image_name = get_image_name_for_local_test()

    yield image_name

    delete_result = delete_docker(image_name)
```

I have a test that use this fixture

```
def test_upload_artifact_to_docker_repo(repo_name, create_docker_image):

    http_port, _ = get_docker_http_port(repo_name, "hosted")

    if http_port == None:
        pytest.skip("the repository defined without http port")

    upload_result = upload_image_to_remote_repo(repo_name)
    assert upload_result == 0
```

For some use case the test can be skipped.

If test was skipped I need ability to skip also the call of `delete_docker` method in the fixture.

How fixture can to know if the test was skipped?

Comment: If you skip the test, the fixture isn't invoked and the call to `delete_docker` won't be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Making test result information available in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) in the docs

Implement `pytest_runtest_makereport` in `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
```

And check the results in the fixture using `request`

```
@pytest.fixture
def create_docker_image(request):
    image_name = get_image_name_for_local_test()
    yield image_name
    if not request.node.rep_call.skipped:
        delete_result = delete_docker(image_name)
```

Comment: That's really cool, I was searching how to access this from pytest-bdd and this did the trick :)